# Pointer arithmetic and const qualifier in C

Tags: c++, c

In the following piece of code, to calculate strlen,

```
int s(const char* str)
{   
    int count=0;        
    while(*str++) count++;
    return count;
}
```

You can see that the argument str is const. But, the compiler does not complain when I do a str++. My question is

**When passing pointers as arguments to a C function, if is is qualified with const, How can I still perform pointer arithmetic on it? What is const in the above function?**

Comment: Thanks! So, if I were to parenthesize the above declaration as the compiler would see it, it would look like (const char) *str, making the  const qualify the char. And if I changed it to const char * const str, it would look like (const char) (const char(*str))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
const char* str;
```

means a non-const pointer to a const data.

```
char* const str;
```

means a const pointer to a non-const data.

```
const char* const str;
```

means a const pointer to a const data.

The reason for this is that in C++ the variable type declarations are parsed from right to left, which results in that the word "const" always defines the constness of the thing that it's closest to.

Comment: It's not the case to say that variable declaration is parsed from the right to left. The gold rule for this: "declaration mimics use". That's because you might have something more complcated to parse, like `void (* var [])(int, char *)`

Answer (score 5):

It's not declaring the pointer `const`, it's declaring the *thing pointed to* as `const`. Try this:

```
int s(const char* const str)
```

With this declaration, you should get a compile error when you modify `str`.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char * ch; // non-const pointer to const data
char * const ch; // const pointer to non-constant data.

const char * const ch; // const pointer to const data
```

Note:
Also

```
const char * ch;
```

equals to

```
char  const * ch;
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointer points to a `const char`, a read-only character array.